# Cloning an entity in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to save a single object to the database twice. I have this code:

```
using (var ss = NHibHelp.OpenSession())
using (var tt = ss.BeginTransaction())
{
    var entity = new Entity();

    ss.Save(entity);
    ss.Save(entity);

    tt.Commit();
}
```

But this results in only one row being added to the database. How do I insert a single object into the database twice (with two different Ids) ?

Comment: You answer you question. Clone you entity and set other id for cloned. And after this you will be able to save them separate. Why couldn't you do it?

Comment: @RredCat I was hoping there'd be something more simple, as in my real application the entity is part of a quite complex hierarchy.

Comment: @RredCat Not the case. After `Save` is called the first time, session will track the object and the second `Save` will do nothing.

Comment: @HackedByChinese But second time you will save other object with same properties (instead of ID)

Comment: @RredCat It won't. If you saved in two different sessions/transactions, it will, however, that's not recommended either.

Comment: @HackedByChinese I don't get. You want to said that isn't possible in NHibernate save one object and add other new in same session/transaction??

Comment: @RredCat You edited your original comment (or at least, I could have sworn you did). You had said the OP's current code would work (that calling Save twice on the same session would work). I was responding to your original comment.

Comment: @HackedByChinese I didn't. Whatever thanks for your answer. It clarified your point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't do this - NHibernate maintains "object identity" within it's session, so it will  not differentiate between ..well.. the same object.  I would really advise against this, and a better solution would be to look at a way of cloning the object (either via reflection, or a Clone method), and then saving the cloned object.

If you want to ignore my advice above, you can get it to work by evicting the entity from the session, setting it's id back to it's unsaved value (depends on your mapping, but probably 0), and then saving it again.

It might also work if you just called session.Merge(entity) twice (you probably have to reset the id to it's unsaved value after the first call).

Alternatively you could use a stateless session with session.Merge() and then you don't have to evict the entity between Save's.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Clone the entity, should be a deep copy.

   ```
   using (var ss = NHibHelp.OpenSession())
   using (var tt = ss.BeginTransaction())
   {
     var entity = new Entity();
     var clonedEntity = entity.Clone();
     ss.Save(entity);
     ss.Save(clonedEntity);

     tt.Commit();
   }
   ```

If your ID is assigned, remember to create a new ID. Deep copy have some issues with complex entities, if you have inverted collection you need to re-reference them.

2.Open a second transaction in a new session and commit it.

```
var entity = new Entity();
using (var ss = NHibHelp.OpenSession())
using (var tt = ss.BeginTransaction())
{      
     ss.Save(entity);

     tt.Commit();
}

using (var ss = NHibHelp.OpenSession())
using (var tt = ss.BeginTransaction())
{      
     ss.Save(entity);

     tt.Commit();
}
```